# Find all "This page does not exist" in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

I wote some articles on my wiki but made links to pages I was going to create later. Right now When you view the page there is a "page does not exist"

Is there a way to get a list of all of the "page does not exists" on every page on the wiki?

I tried broken redirects but all i get is

> Broken redirects Jump to: navigation, search  The following redirects
>   link to non-existent pages:
>
> There are no results for this report.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "wanted pages" in Mediawiki.  See your `Special:WantedPages` page. One especially useful feature is the pages are ordered by those with the most links, so the most "desired" pages are at the top. On a standard installation it looks like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WantedPages).